# Как задать правильно условие для режимов экрана DeviceOrientation.FaceUp, Portrait и Landscape

Tags: c#, unity3d

> Создал 2 префаба адаптивных меню, **landscapeStatsPanel** и
>   **PortraitStatsPanel**, создал скрипт и прикрепил на префабы.

```
            void Update () {
    if (((Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft) || (Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight)) || (Input.deviceOrientation==DeviceOrientation.FaceUp && (Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft)) || (Input.deviceOrientation==DeviceOrientation.FaceUp &&(Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight)))
    {
        landscapeStatsPanel.SetActive (true);
        PortraitStatsPanel.SetActive (false);
    }else if ((Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.Portrait) || (Input.deviceOrientation==DeviceOrientation.FaceUp && (Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.Portrait)))
    {
        PortraitStatsPanel.SetActive (true);
        landscapeStatsPanel.SetActive (false);

    }

}
```

При включений префаба если девайс в режиме **DeviceOrientation.FaceUp** то не определяется **DeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft** или **DeviceOrientation.Portrait** просто открывает в режиме **LandscapeLeft**.

Посоветуйте как решить вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DeviceOrientation** имеет одно состояние за раз. Соответственно проверка типа **Input.deviceOrientation==DeviceOrientation.FaceUp && (Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft)** всегда будет давать **false** (Проверять одно свойство на 2 разных состояния одновременно).

Возьми за базовое состояние более удобный, например Landscape. FaceUp состояние когда телефон лежит на столе(может и в руках). И при faceUp/facedown ставь этот базовый режим.